# File Enumeration performance between .net core and powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core

I currently need to scan a folder within a c# application for files that match a pattern such as RecordId*.*
The folder currently has several hundred thousand files in it and we cannot change that, at least at the moment.

Doing this:

```
            var folderPath = @"\\server\folder\";
            var options = new EnumerationOptions()
            {
                BufferSize = 64000,
                RecurseSubdirectories = false,
                MatchType = MatchType.Simple,
                MatchCasing =  MatchCasing.CaseInsensitive
            };
            var searchPattern = $"{request.RecordId}*.*";
            var isMediaFileInFolder = _fileSystem.Directory
                .EnumerateFiles(folderPath, searchPattern, options);
```

Would take about 10 minutes to return the list of found files.

However, we can run this within PowerShell ISE and it runs in less than a second.

```
$Directory = "\\server\folder\"
$Filter = "REC1234*.*"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Filter $Filter
```

I tried running the powershell within c# through something like this:

```
public static List<string> PSFiles(string path, string pattern)
{
    try
    {
        ICollection<PSObject> collection = null;
        List<string> returnStrings = new List<string>();
        script = "Get-ChildItem -Path " + path + " -Filter" + pattern;
        using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powerShell.AddScript(script);
            collection = powerShell.Invoke();
        }
        foreach (PSObject obj in collection)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.ToString()))
            {
                foreach(var i in Regex.Split(obj.ImmediateBaseObject.ToString().Trim(), "\r\n"))
                {
                    returnStrings.Add(i.Trim());
                }
            }
        }
        return returnStrings;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

And it took longer to run than the enumerate files attempt with nearly all of the time spent on the powerShell.Invoice(); step.

After testing in Powershell Core, that is also taking over 10 minutes. Further, using the Directory.EnumerateFiles() on .NET took less than a second.

So the question is, is there a way to mirror the performance of file enumeration within .NET when running on .NET Core?

Comment: Powershell runs on .NET and Powershell Core runs on .NET Core. If you want to compare performance with .NET Core try to run this command on Powershell Core. Also try *without* specifying any options. The default is to not recurse subdirectories

Comment: Try repeating the tests multiple times too, in different order. I suspect the second attempt is always faster because the first has caused the OS to cache the folder's contents

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you. I was unaware of Powershell Core. I installed that, ran the script and it ran in the same performance as running the script within the Powershell object in c#. So it does appear to be a .NET Core vs .NET discrepency. I did run both tests multiple times and Powershell .NET takes less than a second vs .NET Core over 10 minutes.

Comment: @DavidJacobsen So you ran the exact same command in a `Windows Powershell` (powershell.exe) window as well as in a `Powershell Core` (pwsh.exe) window, multiple times, and `Powershell Core` was consistently slower?

Comment: @ChadBaldwin correct. I also created a .NET application using Directory.EnumerateFiles and it took less than a second to return the file list. So this appears to be a difference in how file enumeration runs between .Net Core and .Net